# NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for ''django.contrib.auth.views.login''

Tags: django, authentication, django-authentication, django-login

I'm using Django's authentication, and in the login.html template, the following statement is generating an error:

```
{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}
```

> TemplateSyntaxError at /login
>
> Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for ''django.contrib.auth.views.login'' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

This url is defined in my urls.py:

```
(r'^login$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login')
```

I have installed the auth system:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
...
)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

### As of Django 1.10:

As of Django 1.10, it is no longer possible to use the string `'django.contrib.auth.views.login'` in `url()` or the `{% url %}` tag.

First, change your url patterns to use the callable, and name the url pattern. For example:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

url_patterns = [
    url(r'^login$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
]
```

Then update your url tag to use the same name:

```
{% url 'login' %}
```

### As of Django 1.5:

You don't need `{% load url from future %}` any more, just use the quoted syntax (`{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}`) and you're done (see the [Django 1.5 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/)).

### As of Django 1.3:

Note that [as of Django 1.3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#changes-to-url-and-ssi) (as Karen Tracey points out [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6168167/20972)), the correct way to fix this is to add:

```
{% load url from future %}
```

at the top of your template, and then use:

```
{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}
```

### Prior to Django 1.3:

Judging by that error message (note the double single-quotes around the path to the view), I'd guess that the [`{% url ... %}`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?#url) tag doesn't want quotes, try:

```
{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}
```

Comment: @juankysmith - post a new question including your template code and your `urls.py`, and then ping me in the comments on this answer with your question URL and I'll happily take a look.

Comment: Works for me too. Weird that [the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) have the quotes...

Comment: Since this question was written the syntax of the `{% url %}` tag has changed, now it requires quotes (if you're using `{% load url from future %}` in 1.4 or below, or if you're using the development release of Django).

Answer (score 9):

The syntax with quotes is new in Django 1.3. The correct way to fix the error on 1.3 forward would be to incldue {% load url from future %} in the template.

Comment: I think you should include this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#changes-to-url-and-ssi) to the django  1.3 release note in your answer to provide some context.