# TemplateSyntaxError with django.contrib.auth.views.login

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-authentication

Getting started with Django 1.3 here. Loving the system so far, but struggling on stuff. Also loving stackoverflow for the Q&As. :)

I'm currently working on getting logins & registrations working and I'm getting a TemplateSyntaxError with my login view.

> Template error
>
> In template /templates/login.html, error at line 9
>   Caught SyntaxError while rendering: ('invalid syntax', ('/userProfile/views.py', 47, 52, "\t\treturn render_to_response('login.html', {'form': })\n"))

I've copy-pasted the code from Django's auth documentation for a login view:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load url from future %}

{% block body-content %}

{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Django is breaking on the following line -

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
```

I've tried removing the single quotes, adding quotes, removing the future url loading but nothing seems to be working. I've read the [NoReverseMatch question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578685/noreversematch-while-rendering-reverse-for-django-contrib-auth-views-login) but it doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: It says you have an error in your `views.py`? There is SyntaxError, not NoReverseMatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in your template but rather in your `views.py` file, line 47:

```
return render_to_response('login.html', {'form': })
```

The `render_to_response` function expects a template name (here: `login.html`) and a dictionary (here: `{'form': }`). However, your dictionary contains a syntax error: You have provided a key (`form`) but are missing a value.

The correct syntax should be something like:

```
return return render_to_response('login.html', {'form': my_form})
```

Comment: Frustrating thing was that was what I had:  
`return render_to_response('/registration/login.html', {'form': form,})`
I removed the url from the action (replacing it with ".") and my view worked.

Answer (score 0):

Like demalexx wrote the problem is in userProfile/views.py. According to error message it looks like your context dictionary is invalid. Key 'form' hasn`t got its value.