# Redirect to admin for login

Tags: django

I have a view defined for a url 'site/main/'.  I would like to be able to have (unauthenticated) users redirected to the default '/admin/' page for login, then redirected to the '/main/' page after successful login.  I followed the django documentation, but I must be missing something as I am unable to get this to work.
My view looks like:

```
def main(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('admin/?next=%s' % request.path)
    else:
```

I get an error:

**Page not found** (404)
**Request Method**: GET
**Request URL**:http://sitename:8080/main/admin/?next=/main/

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: Thanks to @daniel-roseman for the answer.  One small change was required when following the directions.  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578685/noreversematch-while-rendering-reverse-for-django-contrib-auth-views-login">views.login</a>.  I encountered the same error as <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578685/noreversematch-while-rendering-reverse-for-django-contrib-auth-views-login" title="example">NoReverseMatch while rendering</a>, which has the solution.

Comment: To catch up with your issue, it would be easier if you also state the imports. Here: from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing an initial `/` in the URL: `/admin/?next=...`

However this still won't work, as the `admin` URL doesn't know anything about the `next` parameter. That's only for the actual login views. With your code, the user will be logged into the admin but will not be redirected back to your page.

You should build a login template and wire it up to the built-in login views. Then instead of checking `is_authenticated` in the view, you should just use the `login_required` decorator.

```
@login_required
def main(request):
   ...
```

Comment: exactly what I experienced after adding the '/' to the '/admin/'.  The part where you lose me is "You should build a login template and wire it up to the built-in login views."  I'm not quite sure how to wire it up... and building the login template... I'm VERY new to django (if that isn't clear already :-) )

Comment: It's fully explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login

Comment: Thanks !  One small change was required when following the [directions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login).  I encountered the same error as [NoReverseMatch while rendering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578685/noreversematch-while-rendering-reverse-for-django-contrib-auth-views-login) , which has the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your `request.path` shouldn't be `/main/`. Try it without the first.

Comment: thanks !.... changing HttpResponseRedirect('admin/?next=%s) to: HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/?next=%s)  does actually redirect the user the the login screen (which is great !).... but the  "next=main" doesn't seem to be respected...once logged in the user remains on the admin page... any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

1. urls.py:

   ```
                        url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
   ```
2. registration/[login](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views).html:

```html
  <h3>Login foo</h3>
    <form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
```

3. views.py

   ```
   def only_for_users(request):
      if not request.user.is_authenticated():
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/?next=%s' % request.path)

      // fetch some really interesting data

      env=(django.get_version(),settings.BASE_DIR,sys.version)
      envMod=collections.OrderedDict(sorted(sys.modules.items()))
      return render(request,'env.html',{'env':env, 'envMod':envMod})
   ```

It works for Django 1.6 and uses the built-in login (look at the urls.py) and template. So you do not need to build a view function.

Info on [urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#using-the-views)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to   `redirect to admin for login`   for specific view, and then to   `redirect back to the view url` after successful login you only need to do two things:

> 1. Add `LOGIN_URL` to `settings.py` inside your  `django project module`:

```
...
LOGIN_URL = '/admin/login/'
```

> 2. Add `@login_required` as decorator to your view function inside `views.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
...
@login_required
def main(request):
```

> Once you set `LOGIN_URL = '/admin/login/'` you can use `@login_required` on whatever `view` in entire django project  and it  `will redirect to admin for login`  and  `after successful login will redirect back`  to the view url.
>
> Also now you don't need to use `is_authenticated` any more inside of a view as **Daniel Roseman** already said.
>
> The good thing is that now you also **don't need** to build a login template and wire it up to the built-in login views.

What is also good with this approach is the you have **flexibility** to easily add or remove this kind of **authentication** to whatever view you want.