# How to override Django admin login next url

Tags: django, django-login

I'm trying to redirect to current page after login. But it always redirect to admin page. How can I override it.

**view.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='/admin')
def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('visualize/visualize_home.html')
    return render(request,'visualize/visualize_home.html')
```

After successful login url is look like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/?next=/visualize/
```

But I'm expecting

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/visualize/
```

Comment: This link can help you.  
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122293/redirect-to-admin-for-login][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122293/redirect-to-admin-for-login